# how to use main.php in modules in Yii

Tags: yii, yii-modules

I'm creating an admin dashboard in Yii. here is my structure

```
 - Protected
|
 - Modules
|
 -- Views
|
 ---Layouts
|
 --- main.php
 --- column1.php
 --- column2.php
|
 - Themes
|
 -- Bootstrap
|
 --- Views
|
 --- Admin
|
 ---- Layouts
|
 ---- main.php
```

for some reason, my admin panel keeps reading the main.php in the bootstrap folder instead of `/modules/admin/views/layouts/main.php`

```
/**
 * Base class for all admin controllers.
 */
class AdminController extends CController
{

    /**
     * @var string the default layout for the controller view. Defaults to '/layouts/column1',
     * meaning using a single column layout. See 'protected/modules/admin/views/layouts/column2.php'.
     */
    public $layout = '/layouts/column2';

    /**
     * @var string the pageTitle of the current page.
     */
    public $pageTitle = "";

    /**
     * @var array the breadcrumbs of the current page. The value of this property will
     * be assigned to {@link CBreadcrumbs::links}. Please refer to {@link CBreadcrumbs::links}
     * for more details on how to specify this property.
     */
    public $breadcrumbs = array();

    /**
     * @var array admin context menu items. This property will be assigned to {@link TbMenu::items}.
     */
    public $adminMenu = array();

    /**
     * @return array action filters
     */
    public function filters()
    {
        return array(
            'accessControl', // perform access control for CRUD operations
        );
    }

    /**
     * Specifies the access control rules.
     * This method is used by the 'accessControl' filter.
     * @return array access control rules
     */
    public function accessRules()
    {
        return array(
            array('allow',
                'users' => array('@'),
            //'expression' => 'Yii::app()->user->isAdmin'
            ),
            array('deny', // deny all users
                'users' => array('*'),
            ),
        );
    }

    public function beforeRender($view)
    {
        if ($this->adminMenu && !Yii::app()->user->isGuest)
            $this->renderPartial('/layouts/clips/_admin_clip');

        return parent::beforeRender($view);
    }
}
```

here is my column2.php

```
<?php /* @var $this Controller */ ?>
<?php $this->beginContent('/layouts/main'); ?>
<div class="row">
    <div class="span2" id="sidebar">
        <?php
        //a clip is a piece of captured output that can be inserted elsewhere.
        if (isset($this->clips['adminMenuClipID']))
            echo $this->clips['adminMenuClipID'];
        ?>
    </div>
    <div class="span10" id="main-content">
        <?php echo $content; ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php $this->endContent(); ?>
```

how do i make it ready `main.php` from `/modules/admin/views/layouts/main.php` ?

Comment: you can write 'application.modules.layout.main.php' where your are setting layout

Comment: `public $layout = 'application.modules.layout.main.php';` don't work. now the column2.php isn't included

Comment: look, you can use same statement. actually application refers to the protected folder. when using accessing folder from with in another folder so you have to use application. u can use 'application.modules.layouts.column2.php'

Comment: nope. don't work either. it reads column1.php and column2.php correctly. just uses the wrong main.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to alter the path to the decorative view that your view calls in [`CController::beginContent()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CBaseController#beginContent-detail):

```
$this->beginContent('application.modules.admin.views.layouts.column2')
```

assuming the path is `modules/admin/views/layouts/column2.php`

Comment: nope. don't work either. using this, `public $layout = '/layouts/column2';` it reads `column1.php` and `column2.php` correctly. just uses the wrong `main.php` when generating the page.

Comment: change that in my column2.php? as in change this? `$this->beginContent('/layouts/main');`

Comment: Yes. And in `column1.php` or any other layout in which you want to use a different decorative view (in your case `main.php`)

Comment: hmmm it still doesn't include the main. `<?php $this->beginContent('application.modules.views.layouts.main'); ?>
<div class="row">
    <div class="span2" id="sidebar">
        <?php
        //a clip is a piece of captured output that can be inserted elsewhere.
        if (isset($this->clips['adminMenuClipID']))
            echo $this->clips['adminMenuClipID'];
        ?>
    </div>
    <div class="span10" id="main-content">
        <?php echo $content; ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php $this->endContent(); ?>`

Comment: *include the proper main.php

Comment: The folder structure and the path to main.php you put in the question are different. I've updated the answer to use the path to main.php. If this is wrong adjust accordingly.

Comment: works. thanks. so basically, anytime i wanna call a view in modules folder i have to use `$this->beginContent('application.modules.admin.views.layouts.main');` instead of `$this->beginContent('/layouts/main');` ?? is this the only solution? or are there other ways? sorry new to Yii